# is there any way to get coverage badges in Bitbucket like we have in GitHub using Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, cicd

References →
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-12797

https://github.com/jenkinsci/embeddable-build-status-plugin

https://github.com/dwyl/repo-badges

I have a variable in shell script which stores the linting score/coverage score of the code, I want this variable to be used in my Jenkins file and shown in Bitbucket in form of badges.